# Bindewörter (wie "von" oder "des") benötigt zwischen Substantiven in Titelzeilen?

Tags: preposition, article

Ich habe folgende Titel (keine Sätze, nur Titel):

- > Evaluation Registrierung und Login
- > Evaluation Datensammlung
- > Evaluation Datenfreigabe

Muss nach dem Wort *Evaluation* zwingend *von*, *der* oder *von der* stehen oder kann ich es auch so stehen lassen?

Also z.B. *Evaluation Datensammlung*, *Evaluation von Datensammlung*, *Evaluation der Datensammlung* oder *Evaluation von der Datensammlung*?

Comment: Ein Doppelpunkt nach "Evaluation" könnte auch reichen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zwei Substantive stehen selten unverbunden hintereinander, wenn sie kein Kompositum bilden. In fast allen Fällen muss sie irgendetwas verbinden. So auch hier: Es geht um die Evaluierung *von* Sachen oder die Evaluierung *einer* Sache. Dementsprechend muss entweder ein *von* oder ein Genitivartikel dazwischenstehen.

- > Evaluierung von Registrierung und Login

  Da es sich hier um zwei verschiedene Sachen handeln, die obendrein noch verschiedene grammatikalische Geschlechter haben (die Registrierung, der Login) empfehle ich *von*
- > Evaluierung der Datensammlung
  >   Evaluierung der Datenfreigabe

  Da es sich hier jeweils um nur ein Substantiv handelt, das auch noch in der Einzahl steht, ist ein Genitiv stilistisch in der Regel bevorzugt. Es wäre auch möglich *von der* zu verwenden (also *von* + Dativartikel), das macht aber einen stilistisch schlechteren Eindruck.

Es ist mir erst aufgefallen, als ich schon fertiggeschrieben habe, aber ich bevorzuge *Evaluierung* gegenüber *Evaluation*; letzteres klingt sehr nach einer Direktübersetzung aus dem Englischen.

Comment: Super, das hilft mir schon mal sehr viel. Vielen herzlichen Dank!

Comment: Man sollte aber vielleicht doch hinzufügen, dass eine solche (extreme) Verkürzung (durch Weglassen des Artikels o.ä.) in manchen spezifischen Verwendungszusammenhängen durchaus üblich ist, z.B. in der Kurzfassung eines Inhaltsverzeichnisses einer technischen Anleitung, einer Gesetzessammlung usw., v.a. wenn es noch nicht der endgültig zu druckende Text ist sondern noch im informellen Verkehr zwischen Kollegen hin und her geht.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Ist wohl nicht falsch, fällt aber wohl in die Kategorie »Schön geht anders« ;)

Comment: In der Tat. Dort fällt es hin.

Comment: Wenn es sich hierbei um (sub-) Überschriften von Abschnitten handelt, kann man im Interesse einer knackig-prägnanten Darstellung meiner Ansicht nach auch auf den Artikel bzw. das "von" verzichten. Aber +1 für den Hinweis auf *Evaluierung* statt *Evaluation*